# Why i can not load webdav module?

Tags: webdav, lighttpd

I installed lighttpd and dependecies, commented out in lighttpd.conf the necessary extra module mod_webdav, and tried to start it. but i get this error:

```
[root@WL-0022150E7BD4 root]$ /opt/etc/init.d/S80lighttpd start  
Starting web server: lighttpd
2010-06-26 10:46:01: (plugin.c.162) dlopen() failed for: /opt/lib/lighttpd/mod_webdav.so File not found 
2010-06-26 10:46:01: (server.c.643) loading plugins finally failed
```

Anybody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the webdav module separately as it is not part of the standard lighttpd distribution. Assuming you're using Debian kernel:

```
$apt-get install lighttpd-mod-webdav
```

Will get the module installed and you should be able to see mod_webdav.so under /usr/lib/lighttpd.